# After adding resource tag in applicationcontext.xml throws 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am adding css and js folder to resource folder and try to access it from jsp page which is recides in web-inf folder throwing 404 error when I am going to add  tag:

applicaton-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
</beans>
```

If i remove  tag, application is up and its working fine.
I am getting that this error occur due to application unable to find "resources" folder.

[image: Project Structure]